# "Which is why" vs. "that is why"

Tags: grammar, difference

Could tell me if there is any difference in meaning and usage between *which is why* and *that is why*? For example:

> I don't like hot weather, **which is why** I mostly stay in.
>
> I don't like hot weather, **that is why** I mostly stay in.

I can't see any difference whatsoever. Is it just a matter of style which one to use.

Comment: No, it's a matter of grammar. Your first example with a non-defining relative clause example is fine. But "that" can't be used in non-defining relatives, so in your second example, the _that_ clause should be an independent clause, set apart by heavier punctuation like a semi-colon: "I don't like hot weather; that is why I mostly stay in".

Comment: Thank you for your help! What about it was spoken, would be there any difference?

Comment: No difference in speech. Both would have a slight pause before "which" or "that".